# Send delayed email

Tags: email

Is there a way to send a delayed email with Gmail or any other mail client?

I would like to be able to select a time delay before clicking send and then the message would not actually be sent for a certain period of time.

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/9313/send-an-email-at-a-future-date. However, see [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/670178/33589) for the best alternatives as of Nov 2013.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to send a delayed email
>   with gmail **or any other mail
>   client**?

You can do this with **[Thunderbird 2](http://www.filehippo.com/download_thunderbird/6055/)** and the **[Send Later addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/4791)**, here's a step-by-step tutorial:

**[How to Send an Email at a Specific Time in the Future Using Mozilla Thunderbird.](http://www.wikihow.com/Send-an-Email-at-a-Specific-Time-in-the-Future-Using-Mozilla-Thunderbird.)**

Thunderbird is free open source software (FOSS), a portable version is available [here](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/thunderbird_portable/localization#legacy).

Comment: What if your Thunderbird is not running at that time? Quite common when dealing with other time zones, if you travel etc. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/670178/33589) for much better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook, for some versions already, can delay the sending of emails. This is done in the Message Options:

[image]

And of course, you can retrieve Google Mail's messages without problems using Outlook.

Comment: I believe the option in Outlook requires you to have your Outlook client open at the time you have scheduled the email for. It basically sits in your local Outbox until the time passes and the next Send/Receive occurs.

Comment: Worth also noting that when the email arrives at the recipient then (in the same organisation at least) the date and time sent is that of when you pressed "send" - and not when you set the "do not deliver before" time. This is so you can't fool your boss into thinking you are at work when you are really still in bed.

Comment: See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/670178/33589) for much better solutions than Outlook and having to run your machine 24/7.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Boomerang for Gmail](http://www.boomeranggmail.com/). It allows you to schedule an email in Gmail to be sent later and set easy email reminders. It is a Chrome and Firefox extension/addon.

Comment: +1 for the great recommendation. I signed up for a similar service DeferredSender, but never used it because it wasn't as simple as this (plus DeferredSender seems to no longer exist).

Comment: Boomerang is limited to 10 free messages per month. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/670178/33589) for much better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Despite requests for this feature since 2009, the Gmail team [refused](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/JovisjFkzY8) to implement it.

There are however browser extensions and apps that let you schedule new emails or replies:

- **[Streak](http://streak.com)** is a free browser extension CRM for Gmail and has a "Send later" feature (you don't need to bother with the CRM at all). You can conveniently schedule a reply right from the Compose box. I've been using it for about a year and it works very well, except that if I change the Subject line, the message won't go through. You need to go in Drafts and Send it Later from there again, under the new Subject line. Works for Google Apps accounts, as well as Gmail. **Best choice.**
- [RightInbox](http://www.rightinbox.com/) is free for up to 10 emails per month, and supports email tracking via an embedded image (web bug). I've used it in its early stage while it was very buggy and corresponded with its author. You can schedule replies right from the Compose window.
- [Boomergang](http://www.boomeranggmail.com/) is free for up to 10 emails per month. After that, it's $5/mo for Gmail accounts and $15 for Google Apps accounts.
- [Gmail Delay Send](https://code.google.com/p/gmail-delay-send/) is a script you have to install via Google Docs. I tried it; the process was somewhat convoluted and the tool is rough and immature. It is however fully free and open source, and won't add any additional load to your browser (unlike extensions). **This is the most promising and most lightweight solution**. Unfortunately, it has seen [no development since May 2012](https://code.google.com/p/gmail-delay-send/source/list).
- [Momento Mail](http://www.kymalabs.com/mmail) is a Google App (not a browser extension), and you have to use their own website. As of November 2013, it no longer works (directs to a blank page after typing in the scheduling and recipient info). To schedule a reply, you'd have to copy/paste the To, CC and email body from Gmail. Quite cumbersome. Their "To" field doesn't support the standard address format
  `Name <address@company.com>`. The message won't end up in your Gmail Sent folder, but you have an option to BCC yourself. Least recommended.

<sub>(Cross-posted from [my WebApps.SE answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2936/can-i-set-an-e-mail-to-send-on-a-timer-within-gmail/42223#42223))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In GMail, currently no (although I could've swear there was something like that in the *Labs*). But, you can always save your email as draft until you're ready to send it.

Comment: *(although I could've swear there was something like that in the Labs)*
Vaguely remember such a thing. April Fools' prank perhaps ?

Comment: No, no ... it was some weird experiment from the Labs. Something along the likes "you send your girlfriend an angry mail, and then decide not to send it ..." - I can't remember the details; since I never used it.

Comment: Isn't that the undo-feature you're thinking of? "Undo Send by Yuzo F
Oops, hit "Send" too soon? Stop messages from being sent for a few seconds after hitting the send button." It's available in labs, but only delays up to 30 secs, so doesn't answer this question.

Comment: Correct, the Gmail team has been refusing to implement this feature since 2008. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/670178/33589) for much better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I create the email I want to send, save it as a draft (including any attachments, etc.), then I set a calendar entry to remind me to send the email on a specific day/time.  This way I don't have to create it when I need it, and if I'm mobile on my iPhone (or any smart phone), I just have to go to my drafts folder, open the message and hit send when I get the appointment reminder.  Almost as good as send later.

Comment: What if you're not awake at that time? Quite common when dealing with other time zones. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/670178/33589) for much better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail-delay-send is a script you can install and use to send mail in gmail at a time in the future. I use it and I like it. Here is the home page: https://code.google.com/p/gmail-delay-send/

Tweak Master's House of Useful Tricks has a great blog post comparing a few different methods for sending delayed gmail, including Gmail-delay-send and Boomerang: http://tweakmasters.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-schedule-e-mail-sending-with.html

Another third party tool I found that looks like it will work: http://www.rightinbox.com/.

Answer (score -1):

I have modified the Formmail script from Matt's Script Archive to provide a scheduled email delivery for users on an apache web server.  For any sysadmin interested in trying this go to

http://www.eleceng.adelaide.edu.au/Personal/dbowler/delaymail/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! [It would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for future reference.

Comment: -1 for only posting a link, and not fixing it after several months. The user was [last seen in May](http://superuser.com/users/131658/david) and [doesn't seem to have contributed anything other than this answer](http://superuser.com/users/131658/david?tab=activity); his account may be a candidate for deletion.

Comment: In addition, the link doesn't seem to be relevant to this question. The mentioned script is for those who are _running mail services_, and for it to be useful, _Google_ (or whatever other provider) would have to install it (which I can almost guarantee they're not going to do).