# Is it possible to schedule a message for future delivery in Mail.app?

Tags: macos, email, apple-mail

Is it possible to schedule a message for future delivery in Mail.app? I know this is possible in Outlook, in Thunderbird, and through [several external apps](https://superuser.com/questions/9313/send-an-email-at-a-future-date).

Can Mail.app do this, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some AppleScripts using iCal to schedule mails. I've not tested this, but the latest version is from May 2010, so theres a chance these may still work.

> http://homepage.mac.com/aamann/Mail_Scripts.html

Comment: I gave these a shot and they seem to be a good solution. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly dumb question - mail.app has to be running for these scripts to send mail at the appointed time, correct? I can't schedule something for 2AM and put my computer to sleep over night, can I?

Comment: I don't know, sorry.