# How to delay emails

Tags: email, delay

Is there a way to delay incoming  e-mails from certain addresses such that they don't show up in the inbox until business hours? (for any client or server, be it Outlook or Thunderbird or whatever)

edit: 
I am looking for a tweak to either a server or client such that it will "hide" messages that have arrived, and not show them to the client/user until a specific time - this can be for any client/server, and I am not looking for a full setup - assuming that I have a working server/client that receives messages already, but I simply don't want to see them until the specified time, how/where would I go about configuring it?

why the simple solution (ignore the emails or set a filter to move them to a new folder) won't work: I can't "un-see" something once I have seen it, and I can't expect others to do this either - moving them to a new folder where there is no access to open (or see the "new message count") it may be a solution, but only if it can also move the messages back into the inbox at the specified time.

Comment: The email client doesn't decide when mail arrives. I thin the easiest solution is that if you don't want to see business emails until business hours, don't check your business email account until business hours. :)

Comment: Then would it be possible to setup at the server level? any examples of how to do that?

Comment: Do you want to delay **incoming** or **outgoing** messages? Your question reads a bit like you are talking about incoming mail, but it'd be better if it was made explicit. Please **[edit]** your question to indicate the answer. For the moment I have voted to put this on hold as unclear, as the answer to that can make quite a difference in what answers are appropriate. If the question does get put on hold, don't despair; just fix it (and any other possible issues raised in comments) and if you do so while it is "on hold", the question will automatically be nominated for possible reopening.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling edited to specify incoming mail

Comment: Do you control your own mail server?  Is it Exchange?

Comment: @Keltari suppose I can choose to create/setup whatever flavor mail server I want, and I have 100% control over it - it can be Exchange if it makes it easier for you

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is quite simple: create a filter that forwards e-mail from those addresses to a new folder, and check it only during business hours. It's not an answer to your question, but it's a solution to your problem.

What occurs to me as an answer to your question would be *you* being your own e-mail administrator, and taking upon yourself the task of configuring every single aspect of message delivery. That would give you the tools to do whatever you wanted with your e-mail - including eventual delivery delays - but then again, it would likely take you way more time than you probably want.

Comment: I think the latter is more what I am looking for, can you specify the details involved in doing such?

Comment: @user2813274 Setting up a mail server is *far* more work than is appropriate to describe in a SuperUser answer. Specialized setups even more so.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I wasn't expecting a full setup.. rather a specific tweak if possible, but I do realize that it is a much harder question than the "delay outbound messages" question. should I just leave the question open for a while, or is it better to close it?

Comment: The question seems fine, but "please specify the details in setting up every single aspect of mail delivery" is not. If there's something preventing use of the simple solution, I'd suggest you edit your question to describe why the "simple" solution won't cut it.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling OK, I edited the question quite a bit, but feel free to edit it further if you think it would benefit for more editing.

Answer (score 0):

When you send an email you can delay the message for a certain period of time. Then you can set the delay until it is business hours.

For Outlook:

1. In the message, on the Options tab, in the More Options group, click Delay Delivery Button image.
2. Click Message Options.
3. Under Delivery options, select the Do not deliver before check box, and then click the delivery date and time that you want.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/delay-or-schedule-sending-e-mail-messages-HP001232817.aspx

The link shows details of how to delay a single message or all messages.

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear, I was looking to delay incoming mail, not outgoing (question has been edited), delays for outgoing emails have been answered [here](http://superuser.com/questions/9313/send-an-email-at-a-future-date)